# c# DataTable Select Wildcard with Int32

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, wildcard

Is it possible to use a wildcard in a `DataTable.Select(filter)` call if the data type of the column is an `Int32`?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String));
DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Age", typeof(Int32));
table.Select("Name like 'b%'); // Works
table.Select("Age like '3%'); // Does NOT work.
```

This actually works in `MySQL`, so I just wondered if its possible in a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to convert to a string and then use wildcards:

```
table.Select("Convert(Age, 'System.String') like '3%');
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx for valid expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but use an asterisk instead of a percentage sign for the wildcard

The syntax for the data table select statement is the same as for a data column expression - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx for all the supported syntax options

Comment: Both * and % should do the same thing - see link in my answer for valid expressions

Comment: @PinnyM: great minds, I'd also included the link. You're right both should be supported. For some reason I've only seen the asterisk used in c#